# How do I get the name from a UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am new to xcode, and I am trying to make a generic button press method. I want it to check the name (not the title) of the button and then I want to do some string manipulation to set some values.

I have a button setup in my ViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button_1_3;
```

Then I have a generic method in my ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *bSender = (UIButton *)sender;

    self.char1Text1.text = bSender.titleLabel.text; // this is the bit that I am not getting
}
```

So a bunch of my buttons are going to have the same text on them, what I want to see is the "button_1_3". I was hoping there was a "bSender.name" option, but I am yet to find it.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: *sidenote:* if your `UIButton` does not get called by other class, no need to set as `@property`.

Comment: Do you want the variable name? If yes, I don't think that's possible. The pointer (button_1_3) contains the address of the object in memory, but the object in memory doesn't know which pointers have a reference to it.

Comment: What's the point of getting the `UIButton` name? If you want to identify which `UIButton` is pressed, you can assign `tag` to each button, and get the `tag` value by `bSender.tag`

Comment: Basically I want a way of parsing info across from the button so I can have one generic button press. So if I have a button called "button1A", "button1B" and "button2A". I want to know that I have to set a variable to the number 1 or 2 and another variable to the letter A or B.

Comment: How about using tags for your purpose?

Comment: I have never used Tags before, I will give that a go. The idea was that I could put multiple details in the button name, that way I would just do some text manipulation to get the parameters. But if this is not an option then I will try something else

Comment: @user3572147, what about the `tag` prropety? why have not you used that? I would not recommend you to combine the _view_ layer with the _model_ in general like this.

Answer (score 4):

Give all your buttons a tag (this can also be done in Interface Builder)

```
button_1_0.tag = 0;
button_1_1.tag = 1;
button_1_2.tag = 2;
button_1_3.tag = 3;
```

In your `buttonPress:` method check the `tag` and show a different text

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *bSender = (UIButton *)sender;
    switch (bSender.tag) {
        case 0:
            self.char1Text1.text = @"first text";
            break;
        case 1:
            self.char1Text1.text = @"second text";
            break;
        case 2:
            self.char1Text1.text = @"thrid text";
            break;
        case 3:
            self.char1Text1.text = @"fourth text";
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what a terrible idea! the outlet collections are always here to store a massive amount of objects instead of messing up the class thousand variables with slightly similar names...

Comment: It's the naming of the original post. You can always set the tags in IB.

Answer (score 2):

Variable names are there for your easy development, but are not retained when you compile your app.

You need to create a mapping between the buttons and their names. One easy way to achieve this is to assign each button a `tag`, and then create a mapping between tags and names. You can then get the name by `_tagNameMapping[@(sender.tag)];`.

Moreover, since tags are numeric, you can `switch(sender.tag)` and decide your logic, if you chose to.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the method below and it will give you what you need:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
{
    NSString* str1 = [sender titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSLog(@"%@", str1);
}
```

Comment: Uhm, the OP mentions that all buttons will have the same titles, so this won't help.

Comment: What do you mean by "all buttons"? In most cases every action has only one button as its sender, so this method will return the sender's title. Then again, if you need a method to return every buttons name you can see my "before edited" answer method!

Comment: Did you even read the question? He wants to connect all buttons to the same action method. This is why he needs to tell the buttons apart.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *bSender = (UIButton *)sender;
    //uh, and don't forget to set button's outlet or it won't work
    if(bSender==self.button_1_3){
         //button pressed is button_1_3..do manipulation for that button.
    }


}
```