# Get name of a UIControl Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, storyboard

I've been searching for this problem for a while...

Let's say I have 5 buttons on my storyboard and I give all of the buttons the same eventhandler for TouchUpInside.

Is it possible to get the Name property of the "clicked" button?

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `Name` Property is retained when you compile the application as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23288378/2399772). Instead, you could consider using these options:

1. Use the `Tag` (which is although an `integer`)
2. Use the `CurrentTitle`
3. Use the `Accesibility Identifier`

Example:

```
partial void UIButton_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
    var tag = sender.Tag;
    var title = sender.CurrentTitle;
    var accesibilityIdentifier = sender.AccessibilityIdentifier;
}
```

The most commonly used approach is to use the `Tag` Property. In doing so, you can also use `switch` cases.